# Normalize Grafana Histogram response time

Tags: histogram, grafana, response-time

I got this histogram in grafana, it represent the distribution of response time of my application.
[My Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yqpM.png)

How can I normalize it? Is there a function on Grafana that allows me to do this?

i have multiple query for every percentiles (50th, 90th, 95th,99th)

they are structured as follows:

```
(histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter="destination",destination_workload=~"$destination_workload"}[1m])) by (destination_workload, destination_workload_namespace, le)) / 1000) or histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_seconds_bucket{reporter="destination",destination_workload=~"$destination_workload"}[1m])) by (destination_workload, destination_workload_namespace, le))
```

Comment: What data source is used and you query this data (as text, please). Also what panel is this?

Comment: I added the queries in the question, the data source is Prometheus

Comment: And what panel type of Grafana is used (showed on the screenshot)?

Comment: the panel type is Histogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll need manually normalize your histograms with the following query:

```
(
    histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter="destination",destination_workload=~"$destination_workload"}[1m]))
        by (destination_workload, destination_workload_namespace, le)) 
    / 1000
    / on() group_left() sum(histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter="destination",destination_workload=~"$destination_workload"}[1m]))
                            by (destination_workload, destination_workload_namespace, le)))
)
or 
    histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_seconds_bucket{reporter="destination",destination_workload=~"$destination_workload"}[1m])) 
        by (destination_workload, destination_workload_namespace, le))
    / on() group_left() sum(histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_seconds_bucket{reporter="destination",destination_workload=~"$destination_workload"}[1m]))
                            by (destination_workload, destination_workload_namespace, le)))
```

Basically, in this query every item is divided by sum of all items.